# Where to find information about Quarkus supported versions?

Tags: java, quarkus

I am currently taking a look on Quarkus, but cannot find any information about supported versions or support times, even after spending an hour on searching the documentation and Red Hat policies. Google also didn't know the answer.

From Pivotal, I am used to having 12 month time til I finally have to go to the next Spring Boot minor or mayor release. Until then, I can expect patches and therefor guarantee my customers some type of stability. [Spring Boot supported versions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions)

Could anyone please point me to any information about the support, release schedule and end of life policies or statements?

Comment: No idea, perhaps someone thought it was not a coding question. I would advise you to contact Red Hat. They offer commercial support and should be able to give you a quote and further details.

Comment: From the releases it looks like "stick to the newest". I would have thought that such a popular framework, based on, as they call it, stable components, would also have some kind of stable version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment Quarkus does not seem to have a LTS strategy. Instead, on their security page they say they only officially support the latest `major.minor` release. From https://quarkus.io/security/#supported-versions:

> The community will fix security bugs for the latest major.minor version published at https://quarkus.io/get-started/.
>
> ```
> Version      Supported  
> latest 2.x   ✅
> older 2.x    ❌
> < 2.0        ❌
> ```
>
> We may fix the vulnerability to older versions depending on the severity of the issue and the age of the release, but we are only committing to the latest version released.

Comment: Interesting that google was not finding this regarding the keyword.... 
Thank you, thats the most official information that I saw so far :)

Comment: Starting with Quarkus 3.2, the first Long-Term Support (LTS) version of Quarkus will be introduced.

Answer (score 2):

If you buy support from RedHat, you *do* get longer support for certain versions of the [Red Hat build of Quarkus](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/jboss_notes/#p_quarkus). It stands to reason, that the community release also receives updates for these versions (and checking the [Quarkus GitHub Releases](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/releases/) seems to confirm that). You quite definitely won't get community support, though, and will be asked to use the latest version.

Edit: [As of July 6th, 2023,](https://quarkus.io/blog/lts-releases/) there will now be general LTS releases for Quarkus, the first of which will be Quarkus 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus mentioned this in their [Quarkus 3.0 announcement](https://quarkus.io/quarkus3/):

> We often get asked about a Quarkus LTS version. The community asked, so we’ll deliver. Starting with Quarkus 3.2, we will introduce the first Quarkus LTS version. We will share more information as we get closer to releasing Quarkus 3.2.